# .tofix(2) Returning more than 2 numbers after decimals

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I have the following code:

Type a value in the Centimeter field to convert the value to Feet:

```
<p>
<label>Centimeter</label>
<input id="inputCentimeter" type="number" placeholder="Centimeter" 
oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" 
onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Feet: <span id="outputFeet"></span></p>

<script>
function LengthConverter(valNum) { document.getElementById("outputFeet").innerHTML=valNum*0.0328084.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

On most inputs, the returns output has the right format, but on some given sizes (for example 155cm) it returns several decimals:

```
155 Cm=4.6499999999999995 Ft
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the prior operation with `()`. It first evaluates the `function` call on the number, so first goes `0.0328084.toFixed(2)` then the result of this with `valNum`.

```
(valNum*0.0328084).toFixed(2)
```

Example

```js
function LengthConverter(valNum) {
   document.getElementById("outputFeet").innerHTML = (valNum*0.0328084).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<p>
<label>Centimeter</label>
<input id="inputCentimeter" type="number" placeholder="Centimeter" 
oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" 
onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Feet: <span id="outputFeet"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Suren...not really experienced in JS, that is big help

Comment: @KVNHNF very glad to help you

Comment: @KVNHNF If this helps you, accept it and help others to find it

Comment: Not sure what you mean by accept it? Thank you for your confirmation

Comment: @KVNHNF you can accept one of the answers as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the value first and then do the rounding up. To calculate the value first, put them inside the parentheses.

```
(valNum*0.0328084).toFixed(2)
```

Your code is modified below.

```html
<p>
<label>Centimeter</label>
<input id="inputCentimeter" type="number" placeholder="Centimeter" 
oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" 
onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Feet: <span id="outputFeet"></span></p>

<script>
function LengthConverter(valNum) { document.getElementById("outputFeet").innerHTML=(valNum*0.0328084).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Don, I have already used the code provided by Suren above!